# SQL Query statement for multiple criteria

Tags: sql

I need to add more `Dest_Cities` to the following statement, but I keep getting a Syntax error.

I'm verse in VBA, but kinda new to SQL.

```
#(lf)--  a.carrier#(lf)from trident.dbo.vwZCONTK **a#(lf)where a.Dest_City = 'E27'**#(lf)and a.carrier <> 'Y4' #(lf))"]),
```

Comment: This is not SQL. Did you paste the correct code?

Comment: What SQL DBMS product is this?  And what tool are you using to execute this.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
Select a.carrier from trident.dbo.vwZCONTK where a.dest_city in ('e27','citi_nameA','citi_nameB') and a.carrier <> 'Y4'
```

Comment: Here is the entire statement:

Comment: @GaryCarpenter did you forget to put link?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the statement:
let
    Source = Sql.Database("SCSQLBI02", "trident", [Query="(select distinct#(lf)  a.xblnr as Container,#(lf)  a.MBL_ASN as MBN,#(lf)  --FORMAT( GETDATE(), 'd', 'en-gb')#(lf)  format(a.actual_del_date, 'd','en-us') as [Actual Delivery],#(lf)  format(a.Date_Empty, 'd','en-us') as [Date Empty],#(lf)  format(a.takenout_date, 'd','en-us') as [Taken Out Date],#(lf)  a.port_dischg as [Discharge Port Name],#(lf)  a.Dest_city as [Destination City Code],#(lf)  a.Truck_com as [Trucking Company],#(lf)--  a.Carrier as Carrier,#(lf) case when a.Carrier = 'Z2' then 'APL'#(lf)  when a.Carrier = 'HS' then 'Hamburg-Sud'#(lf)  when a.Carrier = 'Z6' then 'Hapag'#(lf)  when a.Carrier = 'Z8' then 'Maersk'#(lf)  when a.Carrier = 'MS' then 'MSC'#(lf)  when a.Carrier = 'OO' then 'OOCL'#(lf)  when a.Carrier = 'ZM' then 'ZIM'#(lf)  when a.Carrier = 'ON' then 'ONE'#(lf)  when a.Carrier = 'Z4' then 'Evergreen'#(lf)  when a.carrier = 'Y4' then 'AIR'#(lf)  else 'Unknown' end as [Carrier Name]#(lf)--  a.carrier#(lf)from trident.dbo.vwZCONTK a#(lf)where a.Dest_City = 'E27'#(lf)and a.carrier <> 'Y4' #(lf))"]),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each [Actual Delivery] <> null and [Actual Delivery] <> ""),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Filtered Rows",{{"Actual Delivery", type date}, {"Date Empty", type date}, {"Taken Out Date", type date}})
in
    #"Changed Type"

Comment: you can edit your own Q to share the code. And I guess you are sharing VBA script which has to be translated to sql. is it right?

Answer (score 0):

I think this represents the correct SQL from your VB formatted post (its ok, you'll learn posting for readability).

If you specifically had all those "#(lf)" line feed representations in your query, that was probably choking it...  Otherwise it may have been the <> (not equal).

Also, as a side-note when doing queries and building result column names, it is typically more of a PITA to have embedded spaces in column names.  Keep them CamelCaseFormatted.  They are still readable, but a single column name and prevent the need of [square bracketing] through rest of code.  You can always have your output format the headings with proper spaces.

So from your example output columns of [Actual Delivery], change to just ActualDelivery, similarly for DateEmpty, TakenOutDate, DischargePortName, etc.

Now, the readability of the query without the #(lf) references more readable.

```
select distinct
        a.xblnr as Container,
        a.MBL_ASN as MBN,
        format(a.actual_del_date, 'd','en-us') as [Actual Delivery],
        format(a.Date_Empty, 'd','en-us') as [Date Empty],
        format(a.takenout_date, 'd','en-us') as [Taken Out Date],
        a.port_dischg as [Discharge Port Name],
        a.Dest_city as [Destination City Code],
        a.Truck_com as [Trucking Company],
        case when a.Carrier = 'Z2' then 'APL'
            when a.Carrier = 'HS' then 'Hamburg-Sud'
            when a.Carrier = 'Z6' then 'Hapag'
            when a.Carrier = 'Z8' then 'Maersk'
            when a.Carrier = 'MS' then 'MSC'
            when a.Carrier = 'OO' then 'OOCL'
            when a.Carrier = 'ZM' then 'ZIM'
            when a.Carrier = 'ON' then 'ONE'
            when a.Carrier = 'Z4' then 'Evergreen'
            when a.carrier = 'Y4' then 'AIR'
            else 'Unknown' end as [Carrier Name]
    from 
        trident.dbo.vwZCONTK a
    where 
            a.Dest_City = 'E27'
        and NOT a.carrier = 'Y4'
```

As for your #"Filtered Rows"  and  #"Changed Type", you appear to be stripping further from the result set on the VB side (but I'm not a VB guy).  Get your query working and a result "Source" set of records, then work your table filtering rows.